# Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, viewbag

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and need your help with a specific question.

I'm working on a School Application. The app is capable to registers students in db and principal (Admin) can assign them to groups.

Here is code from controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GroupInfo(int id, int grade)
    {
        var groupVM = new GroupViewModel();

        groupVM.Id = id;
        groupVM.Grade = grade;

        foreach (var stud in await userManager.Users.Where(s => s.ApplicationUserType == ApplicationUserType.Student && s.Status == false).ToListAsync())
        {
            var studentViewModel = new StudentInfoViewModel
            {
                Id = stud.Id,
                FirstName = stud.FirstName,
                LastName = stud.LastName,
                Email = stud.Email,
                PreviousGrade = stud.Comments,
                IsSelected = stud.Status
            };

            groupVM.Students.Add(studentViewModel);
        }

        ViewBag.Students = groupVM.Students.Where(s => s.PreviousGrade == groupVM.Grade.ToString()).Select(s => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName + ", Previous grade: " + s.PreviousGrade,
            Value = s.Id
        }).ToList();

        return View(groupVM);
    }
```

The controller assigns free students to groups, but it shows only students who match the grade of the group.
I need to make validation in my view for students who do not match the group grade.

I wanted to make check in my view, here is the code

```
<form method="post" asp-action="GroupInfo" asp-controller="PrincipalProfile" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h2>Add or remove students to current group</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">List of Students</label>
            @if (ViewBag.Students != 0)
            {
                <select asp-for="StudentId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Students">
                    <option selected disabled>Choose a student to add</option>
                </select>
            }
            else
            {
                <span>There are no available students at this grade.</span>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <a asp-controller="PrincipalProfile" asp-action="Groups" class="btn btn-dark">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get RuntimeBinderException when I try to check if the viewbag is seeded with information.

**RuntimeBinderException: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>' and 'int'**

Will be grateful if you share your vision and opinion on how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 @if ( ViewBag.Students!=null &&   ViewBag.Students.Count > 0)
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Gives this exception: RuntimeBinderException: Non-invocable member 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>.Count' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: I removed brackets, and it worked. @if ( ViewBag.Students!=null &&   ViewBag.Students.Count > 0)

Comment: Try just ViewBag.Students.Count